# play 4 rtsp streams in fullscreen

Tags: ubuntu, video, camera

I have 4 IP cameras in my network, and I need to play the 4 streams at once in a grid view,

currently i execute this command:

```
ffplay rtsp://10.1.10.123
```

for each IP and then I rearrange the windows,

**is there any app or a command to play those streams in a grid view in full screen mode?**

something like:
[image]